# Internationalization with Javascript variables

Tags: javascript, internationalization, tapestry

I am using one API which has its own javascript. Now in that javascript file they have declared few variables as follows :

```
monthNames: ['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December'],

monthNamesShort: ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'],

dayNames: ['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday'],

dayNamesShort: ['Sun','Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat']
```

In my application we have implemented internationalization. How can I implement internationalization for above declared variables ?

Comment: Please clarify what this has to do with Java and at least add the JavaScript tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Especially for date and time formatting, I have to suggest [Globalize](https://github.com/jquery/globalize).
It also have ability to simply translate resources (although you would need to write out translated resources from the backend either way).

BTW. If you need some kind of Calendar control, you could use [jQuery UI Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/), which has built-in (partial) [support for i18n](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#localization) and some publicly available [localization files](http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ui/i18n/).

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest some sort of internationalization wrapper. Something along the lines of the following pseudo code:

```
var i18n = {
   longNames: true; 

   getMonth: function(i) {
       if (longNames) 
           return monthNames[i];
       else 
           return monthNamesShort[i];
   }, 

   getDay: function() {
    ....
   }, 
   ...

}
```

If you further wish to translate e.g., the monthNames array you could try something like the following. Using the same principle as above you can also wrap it to abstract away the *language* configuration from each call.

```
var monthNames = {
   "English": ["January", "February", ..., "December"]},
   "French": ...
   ...
]
var englishMonth = monthNames["English"][0]; // January in english
```

};

Comment: What are you not getting? This is the level of detail I can give you based on the details from your original question.